# How to switch the screen after clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "login" screen (entering name only) with the button - without nav links. I want to make an additional screen with different content when the button is clicked, but I can't figure out how to do it.

React version: 18

I tried to add a router, but I didn't know how to set it against the components (I have no links or additional url).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: define a status relation to the button，when the button is clicked, change the status.And then set different screen with corresponding status

Answer (score 0):

To create a new screen in a React application, you can use a router and add routes for each of the screens in your app.

Install the react-router-dom package, which provides the components and functions you need to use routing in React.

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

Import the BrowserRouter, Route, and Link components from the react-router-dom package in your app's entry point (e.g. index.js):

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Wrap your app's root component with the BrowserRouter component to enable routing:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Add a Route component for each screen in your app, specifying the path for the screen and the component that represents the screen. For example, to add a "Profile" screen, you could do the following:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Other components and content here... */}

      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now add an `onClick` event on your button e.g

```
<button type="submit" onClick={onClick}>
        Go to Profile
</button>
```

and this is how you can use:

```
function LoginForm() {
  ....
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const onClick = () => navigate('/profile');
  ....
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but there is one problem - when I click on the button my new view appears in the same view.

Comment: try wrapping your routes in `<Switch>` component. import it from `import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";` This should resolve your issue